# Storing a function inside a bash array element

Tags: bash

How can I define a function as an element of an array?

I know I can do this:

```
function array[5](){ echo "you are inside the function"; }
```

And it is a valid function, in the sense that, the instruction `array[5]`, correctly execute the function.

Unlucky, the function is not listed in the keys of the array, so, `echo ${!array[*]}` does not return `5` as a key.

For instance, the following code:

```
array[0]="first"
function array[5](){ echo "you are inside the function"; }
array[7]="seventh"
echo ${!array[*]}
```

Only returns `0 7`.

**So, how can I add a function to an array element, so that I can loop over it?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't really put the function itself in the array. But what you can do is put the function name in that field. Look:

```
a_pretty_function() {
    echo "you're inside a function";
}
array[5]=a_pretty_function

# Execute it:
"${array[5]}"
```

---

When you're doing

```
array[5]() { echo "you are inside the function"; }
```

you're defining a function called `array[5]` as you can check with `declare -pf array[5]`.

With this mechanism you can do something horribly ugly:

```
array[5]() { echo "you are inside the function"; }
i=5
"array[$i]"
```

and this will execute the function `array[5]`. I wouldn't recommend such a practice in any case.

Comment: Indeed the key is that last bit. Variables and functions don't share a namespace.

Comment: It also demonstrates that `array[5]` isn't so much an index operation as a name that `bash` treats specially for parameter expansion. Arrays are just ugly in `bash`.